# Ionic 7 backwards compatibility with older versions of chrome

Tags: chromium, ionic5, ionic7, browserlist

I developed an app in ionic 5 and I'm switching to ionic 7. ionic 7 no longer supports older versions of Chromium...
I have a device on which I cannot update the browser which has version 69.0.3497.128. do you know how I can force ionic backwards compatibility to be able to show my app on such old versions?